# Get excel cell address in Python 2 using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I have the following scenario:

1. Read the excel file of column A for all active rows
2. Run if else statement: if column A == 'registered', do nothing and just read the next row. Else, get cell address (not value) and do some actions

For example, here is my "sample.xlsx":

[row 1] A1=registered B1=user1

[row 2] A2=registered B2=user2

[row 3] A3=null B3=user3

my code should ignore row1 and row2 and proceed with row 3. In row 3, I should get "A3" and do some actions.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook(filename='sample.xlsx')
sheet = book.active
first_column = sheet['A']

for x in xrange(len(first_column)):
    status = first_column[x].value

    if status == 'registered':
      #enter code to just proceed with the next row

    else:
      #enter code to get the column cell range and do some actions

book.save('sample.xlsx')
```

I got stucked with the scenario 2, I am a newbie in python, I have a code in java using FileScanner but I need it in Python 2. Appreciate your help.

UPDATE:
I already have an answer below but just wondering if there are any other method??

Comment: Could you please share your desired output, it will be easy for others to help.

Comment: Have a look, i just posted an answer.

Answer (score -1):

so far, I have tried these. is there any other method?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook(filename='sample.xlsx')
sheet = book.active
first_column = sheet['A']
checker = 'false'

for x in xrange(len(first_column)):
    status = first_column[x].value
    xaddress = first_column[x].column
    yaddress = first_column[x].row
    celladdress = xaddress+str(yaddress)


    if status != 'registered':
        print celladdress
        checker == 'true'
        break

if checker == 'true':
    #... my actions here ....
```

Here is my "sample.xlsx":

[row 1] A1=registered B1=user1

[row 2] A2=registered B2=user2

[row 3] A3=null B3=user3

Output: A3

Answer (score -1):

Have a look

---

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
   for cell in row:
     if cell.value != "registered":
        print cell.column
        print cell.row
        ## further processing here #######
```

---

No need to write logic for explicit row iteration this `for` loop will take care of that.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: No need to use A1:D4 coordinates with iter_rows()

Comment: @CharlieClark Then please help me with the alternative and best approach

Answer (score -2):

It always helps to read the [documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells)

```
for cell in ws['A']:
    pass
```